# How to access specific values of dictionary which is nested in list on pandas .Need to update this "xId": "000501"

Tags: python, pandas

```
[
    {
        "_id": "001",
        "ca":
        [
            {
                "car": "EM",
                "ind": null,
                "bindOnline": true,
                "isEligible": false,
                "nai": "111421",
                "is": false,
                "xId": "000501"
            },
            {
                "cd": "xyz",
                "i": null,
                "bi": true,
                "isEligible": true,
                "naie": null,
                "internalClassificationCd": "212266"
            }
        ],
        "states":
        [
            "A"
        ],
        "s": "0005",
        "x": ""
    },
```

Comment: It seems that you have a goal, now what have you tried, where are you stuck? ;)

Comment: Missing `]` at the end of json.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `xId` value of a single dictionary (e.g. the one in first position) just run

```
xid = l[0]['ca'][0]['xId']
```

To access all `xId` values contained in all dictionaries of your list and append them to another list

```
xids = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    xids.append(l[i]['ca'][0]['xId'])
```

Answer (score 0):

for a single dictionary, to access xId value use this code

```
item[0]['ca'][0]['xId']
```

for access to all values use below one

```
xIds = [i['ca'][0]['xId'] for i in item]
```